# iOS 11 CoreNFC How Does One Handle Reading Errors?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, core-nfc

CoreNFC has a delegate method for errors being:

```
//Called when the NFC session invalidates with an error.
- (void)readerSession:(nonnull NFCNDEFReaderSession *)session didInvalidateWithError:(nonnull NSError *)error {
}
```

The documentation (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc) shows on the error section (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc/nfcreadererror) a bunch of error codes.

I want to be able to read the error that came from the reader session and put it inside of a switch statement that I can output a different message per error. I can't figure out how to get those error message from the function. I'm assuming I missed something on basic objective c on casting on something.

What I hope to get is something like this.

```
switch (error) {
        case NFCReaderErrorSecurityViolation:
            //Do Stuff
            break;
        case NFCReaderErrorUnsupportedFeature:
            //NFC is unsupported.
            break;
        //ETC
        default:
            break;
    }
```

How do I get that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `error.code` in the switch block as follows,

```
switch (error.code) {
    case NFCReaderErrorSecurityViolation:
        //Do Stuff
        break;
    case NFCReaderErrorUnsupportedFeature:
        //NFC is unsupported.
        break;
    //ETC
    default:
        break;
}
```